# Java ArrayUtils.toPrimitive I can't do ArrayUtils.removeElement

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, arraylist, casting

I am need to use the results from mysql DB call in as an INT array. The problem is, when I retrieve the data via a ResultSet through a IntegerList  and then use **"ArrayUtils.toPrimitive"** I can't do a **ArrayUtils.removeElement**.
But if I would just create an array then I can remove elements.

Here is what I mean:

```
       List<Integer> rowValues = new ArrayList<>();
String MySqlResultStr;
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      while (rs.next()) {
          int gematria = rs.getInt("gematria");
          rowValues.add(rs.getInt(1));
       }
int[] GematriaIntArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(rowValues.toArray(new Integer[0]));
System.out.println("Contents Pre: " + GematriaIntArray.length);
GematriaIntArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(GematriaIntArray, 1);
System.out.println("Contents Pst: " + GematriaIntArray.length);
int GematriaIntArraySize = GematriaIntArray.length;
int GematriaIntTempArraySize = GematriaIntArray.length;;
int GematriaSum = 0;
int PerekIndent = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < (GematriaIntArraySize +1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < GematriaIntTempArraySize; j++)
    {
        GematriaSum = GematriaSum + GematriaIntArray[j];
        System.out.println(GematriaSum + "," + (i+PerekIndent) + "," + (i+j+PerekIndent));
    }
    GematriaSum = 0;
//--The line below does not work!        
GematriaIntArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(GematriaIntArray, i);
    GematriaIntTempArraySize = GematriaIntArray.length;
}
```

vs:

```
int[] GematriaIntArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println("Contents Pre: " + GematriaIntArray.length);
        GematriaIntArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(GematriaIntArray, 1);
        System.out.println("Contents Pst: " + GematriaIntArray.length);
```

Comment: Usually it helps if you tell what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing out of the array. Assume you got an array with a single element (I will use lowercase variable names):

```
for (int i = 1; i < (gematriaIntArraySize +1); i++)
{
    //omitted some code
    //--The line below does not work!        
    gematriaIntArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(gematriaIntArray, i);
}
```

You are asking ArrayUtils to remove the element `1` from the array, although it has only a single element. Use `ArrayUtils.removeElement(gematriaIntArray, i - 1)` and compute the length of the array in each iteration. Something along these lines:

```
for (int i = 1; i < (gematriaIntArray.length +1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gematriaIntTempArraySize; j++)
    {
        gematriaSum = gematriaSum + gematriaIntArray[j];
        System.out.println(gematriaSum + "," + (i+perekIndent) + "," + (i+j+perekIndent));
    }
    gematriaSum = 0;
    gematriaIntArray = ArrayUtils.removeElement(gematriaIntArray, i - 1);
    gematriaIntTempArraySize = gematriaIntArray.length;
}
```

I have not checked what the code does, only the problematic parts, although there might be other problems there too.